# Distinguishing adjective or adverb clause?

Tags: participle-clauses

Which one "A" or "B"  shows the relation between the following sentence?

**"Feeling somewhat overwhelmed by all the attention he was receiving, the young star decided to take a break and go back to his hotel room."**

> A: (adjective clause) "The young star, who was feeling somewhat
>   overwhelmed by all the attention he was receiving, decided to take a
>   break and go back to his hotel room."
>
> B: (Adverb clause) "Because the young star was feeling somewhat
>   overwhelmed by all the attention he was receiving, he decided to take
>   a break and go back to his hotel room."

**Notice:**
It is not my homework. It was written by English teacher in a website. He only wrote the number 1 in her example and I though that maybe number 2 will be correct as well. The second sentence is written by myself.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts yourself? If you do, it would be good for you to add them in so we can comment on them. I wouldn't want to just do your homework for you :p

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it is not my homework. It was written by English teacher in a website. He wrote that Number 1 is correct and I though that maybe number 2 will be correct as well. The second sentence is written by myself.

Comment: Can you edit the question to add that extra information in please? The point about "homework" was meant as a joke, by the way :)

Comment: Sure. I'll do that.

Comment: All three are correct. As you've noted, it just depends on what you want to emphasize: his feeling of being overwhelmed or that he had decided to go back to his hotel room.

Comment: It's neither, and it's not an adjective or adverb clause (even if there were such clauses). It's a gerund-participial clause functioning as a 'supplementary adjunct'. More specifically, it is a 'depictive' adjunct. Such adjuncts are predicative in that they give descriptive information about the subject, in this case "the young star". I wouldn't call it a 'reason' adjunct (as per your B alternant), for two reasons: first, it doesn't assert that his feeling of being overwhelmed ... was actually the reason for taking a break, and second, reason adjuncts are normally PPs, not clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct grammatically, and it depends on the idea you want to express to choose the most suitable one.

If you want to show the causal effect, i.e. to show that the action of taking a break and going back is a result of the overwhelming feeling, sentence B is better. The attention of the reader will focus on not only the action of the young star but also the reason why this action occurs.

Whereas if you want to focus on story and the end action of the young star (taking a break and going back), without any intention to explain why, then the sentence A is better. What the spokesperson is trying to say here is that the young star decided to take a break and go back. The spokesperson then added a relative clause in the middle of the sentence to provide more details about this young star, without any intention to mean that this additional information is the cause for the main content of the sentence.